# Perform stream calculations in app "brain" - An alternative to Stream Builder

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, stream-builder

I am listening to a number of streams with RxDart. I then use a StreamBuilder to process the data as it comes in and update String and int variables that I then display in my app. Streams and variables are displayed below.

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> janFlightsStream(BuildContext context) async* {
    final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection("UserAirTravelInputs")
        .document(uid)
        .collection(formatDate(DateTime.now(), [yyyy, '', '']))
        .where("entryMonth", isEqualTo: "Jan")
        .snapshots();
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> febFlightsStream(BuildContext context) async* {
    final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection("UserAirTravelInputs")
        .document(uid)
        .collection(formatDate(DateTime.now(), [yyyy, '', '']))
        .where("entryMonth", isEqualTo: "Feb")
        .snapshots();
  }

  double janFlightsKm;
  int janNumberOfEntries;
```

StreamBuilder returns a widget which is fine here. But I do this on each screen in my app which is extremely inefficent. I want to extract this logic (of listening to firebase stream data and making calculations based on that data) from each screen to something like a provider or app "brain" which handles this data, so that I only need tp access the output of these calculations when needed in the different app routes.

```
 StreamBuilder<List>(
          stream: CombineLatestStream.list([
            janFlightsStream(context),
            febFlightsStream(context),
          ]),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SpinKitDoubleBounce(
                      color: kDarkBlue,
                      size: 100,
                    ),
                    Text("Loading data..."),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.data[0].documents.length != 0) {
              final janFlights = snapshot.data[0].documents;
              double janTotalGCO2e = 0;
              janNumberOfEntries = snapshot.data[0].documents.length;
              for (var flight in janFlights) {
                double janKm = flight.data["flightKm"];
                janTotalGCO2e += janKm;
              }
              janFlightsKm =
                  double.parse((janTotalGCO2e / 1000).toStringAsFixed(2));
            } else {
              janFlightsKm = 0;
              janNumberOfEntries = 0;
            }
            if (snapshot.data[1].documents.length != 0) {
              //Do something
            } // Do something else
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              appBar: AppBar(),
              body: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(janNumberOfEntries.toString()),
                    Text(janFlightsKm.toString()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

Is there a way to do this without using this repeated StreamBuilder? I have looked in to StreamProvider but appears that only gives the stream of data, and I would then have to process the data again each time I tap in to the StreamProvider which does not solve the problem.

Simply it is 1. list of streams. 2. process data coming from streams (as code above), 3. store that data, and 4. make it available throughout the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [StreamProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html) needs a `Stream` to be returned from its `create` callback so simply return your `CombineLatestStream.list(...)` stream from there

Comment: Thanks, I guess my main issue is where (or how) to perform the calculations.. If I perform them in the create of StreamProvider, then I still have the problem of many lines of unused code. I would like to extract the entire code sequence and return only the output values.

Comment: if you dont want to reapeat those `if (snapshot.data[0].documents.length != 0) {...` then use [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream/CombineLatestStream.html) constructor and not `CombineLatestStream.list` static method - with `CombineLatestStream` constructor you can use `combiner` where you return a stream with your own, custom combined data

Comment: You can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/map.html. map method of the stream to do your calculations based on the latest data you receive. map method returns a stream so maybe you can use that

Comment: Thank you both. I can get this working using CombineLatestStream.combine and access the .documents property as nedded. However, I have more than 9 streams (the limit of .combine method) and using the CombineLatestStream constructor I only return an instance of a QuerySnapshot. Any idea on how to access the .documents property??

Comment: *"However, I have more than 9 streams (the limit of .combine method)"* - [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream/CombineLatestStream.html) constructor has no such limits